# LibGDX Обработка нажатий на отдельную часть Actor

Tags: java, android, libgdx

У меня есть прямоугольный "Actor", а внутри квадрат, по нажатию на который должно происходить действие.

Как сделать так, чтобы не весь "Actor" реагировал на нажатие, а только лишь небольшая область внутри него?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно наследовать примоугольник не от `Actor`, а от `Group`, в `Group` добавить актера(квадрат) методом `addActor (Actor actor)`, и накинуть лисенер дочернему актеру

```
actor.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: В том весь и прикол, что необходимо было сделать нового актёра из нескольких старых. Не помогло и наследование не от Actor, а от Group